# What is the common name for Organisation and Company?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I need to give a title for the list which contains companies and organizations.

I have heard Organisation ( Mostly non-profit) and Companies (Profit based) . Our list contains both types of entities. So I am looking for a common name to users understand easily.

Comment: What's the difference? Aren't companies also organisations of sorts? I would suggest a better name for whatever you are calling "organisations". But for your list title you could use "Entities", "Clients", "Things to avoid", "Future prospects to contact" -- we don't know enough about the situation to suggest anything uniquely suitable.

Comment: I have heard Organisation ( Mostly non-profit) and Companies (Profit based) . Our list contains both types of entities. So I am looking for a common name to users understand easily.

Comment: *Organization* is fine. Under it, you can have *for profit* and *not for profit*. You could also have *governmental*. The former two are *private sector*, the latter *public sector*.

Answer (score 1):

Organisation is the common word. A company is a type of organisation. An organisation could be for profit or not.

Answer (score -1):

If these organizations and companies fall under a single umbrella ownership-wise you could use:

**Conglomerate**: adj./noun "Consisting of heterogeneous parts or elements."

Comment: Downvote because?? I'm fine with someone not liking my answer but at least say why. I'd rather someone dissuade the OP for a particular reason as opposed to there just being a downvote with no context.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I suspect the one who did thought that "conglomerate" applies usually to very large companies, and hardly ever to charities or "non-profits"